# Not able to create android apk file using command line ant

Tags: android, apk

In the android project, I run the following steps

1. android update project -p . --target android-19
2. ant release

But I am not able to get the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by doing ant clean.

So this solved my problem.

Thanks

Deepak Bhatia